# CKEditor in a modal (ng2-bs3-modal) with angular2

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have a weird problem using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in my angular2 Project.
I use [ng2-bs3-Modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal) for modal dialogues.

Basically i have two views, one is a list view with a button, which opens up a modal with some form fields and a ckeditor instance. The other view is not really important, but the problem i'm experiencing is happening after view changes.

To work with CKEditor in my project i included the Typescript Definition from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ckeditor).

Now the magic happens in my modal component. It has a `open` function which is called by its parent component, to open the modal (and setting up some stuff for the modal).

If the modal is closed, the `cancel` function is called. 
So simplified, my component currently looks like this:

```
import ...
@Component({ ... })

export class MyModalComponent implements OnInit {

   @ViewChild('messageModal')
   private _modal:ModalComponent;

   private _ckEditorInstance:any;

   open(message?:Message) {

        ...

        this._ckEditorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('ck-editor', {
            allowedContent: 'p a b i u font br ol ul li'
        });

        this._ckEditorInstance.on('instanceReady', () => {
            this._ckEditorInstance.setData(this.currentEditorText);
        });

        this._ckEditorInstance.on('pasteState', () => {
            this.currentEditorText = this._ckEditorInstance.getData();
        });

        ...


        this._modal.open();
        this._ckEditorInstance.setData(this.currentEditorText);
     }

     ...

     cancel() {
         for(let instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
             CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy();
         }

         this._modal.close();
      }
}
```

### The problem:

If i navigate to the list-view and open up the modal, everything works as expected. I can close the modal, open it again, everything's good. BUT if i open it, close it, navigate to another view and back to my list-view again, click the button to open the modal, the CKeditor `replace` method or something else isn't working, so i have a normal `textarea` where the CKEDitor instance is supposed to be.

---

Now, i already tried a bunch of stuff, first i haven't had the `destroy logic` in my cancel function which led to an instance error by ckeditor. 
I also tried importing `RuntimeCompiler` and use the `clearCache` function in my `open` function like this: `this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache()` because i thought it could be a caching problem. As far as i understood, this function clears the entire template cache, so if it was a caching problem it should be solved by this (it obviously wasn't).

If it does matter, i navigate to the list-view via a `routerLink` so pretty basic. (Haven't tried a routeChange programmatically, a site reload would probably solve the problem, but is a no-go for me.)
Another approach i thought about is to remove and add back the `textarea` to my modal template everytime i open (or close) it, but this doesn't feel right and i don't think it could solve the problem. I might try that now.

I don't have any other ideas at the moment.

Any solution for this? Appreciate any thoughts or hints.

Answer (score 1):

For now, i found a solution, but i'm not going to set this as accepted answer yet, cause it's just a workaround and i did not yet understand why this has anything to do with the Route changes.

I hope someone can provide a better answer.

What i did is to add a boolean property to my component `textareaInitialized:boolean;` and in my template i use `*ngIf` on my textarea wrapper like this:

```
<div *ngIf="textareaInitialized">
    <textarea name="ck-editor" id="ck-editor"></textarea>
</div>
```

Now in my `open` function i set this to true and wrapped the rest of the `open func` code in a `setTimeout( () => ..., 0);` and in my `cancel` function i just set it back to false. This way the textarea is readded everytime i open the modal and therefore initializing the CKeditor instance works fine.